# What is the best program to uncompress .tar.gz files on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, tar

What is the best program to uncompress .tar.gz files on Windows Server 2008?

EDIT:

Sorry - 'Best' is very subjective.

In my situation speed and the ability to both unzip and untar in one step are important.

From what I've read (on the 7-zip front page!?)- 7-zip has the best outcome when it comes to compression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [WinRar](http://www.rarlabs.com), it does the tarballing and gz'ing in one step.

Comment: Looks like WinRar is just as good an option - unfortunately you came in second! Let the voting decide 'the best'...

Comment: Haha, well it's not a competition

Comment: WinRAR is a far superior product to 7-Zip (for features)

Comment: Izzy, only for the RAR format. Besides, 7-Zip is free.

Comment: Mind you, the only person I know who's admitted to buying a WinRAR license is Jeff Attwood

Comment: I just realised that I needed to unzip and untar in one step... so for me this is the answer. 7-zip got the votes though:)

Comment: @ Farseeker: Nah, I bought a WinRAR license, too. I think the fact that I only use 7-Zip now speaks volumes  ;)

Comment: Interesting... I had no idea 7Zip was so popular. My only exposure to it was about 5 years ago and I hated every moment of it, and switched to WinRAR almost immediately...

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if this one is "the best", but you can try [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

Comment: 7-Zip does not extract tar.gz in one step. http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/5eb1b8d5/?page=0

Answer (score 3):

YOu can use Gnu [Tar](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar) and [GZip](http://www.gzip.org/) for Windows.

Comment: +1: using command line is rarely a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is very subjective. One I use quite a lot is [Tugzip](http://www.tugzip.com/), which like 7-Zip is free.

Comment: You're right - I've edited the question.

Comment: I forgot to mention WinZip, which also does a very nice job of it.